# Goole Maps API (Direction from place A to place b) with JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to do:

1. Get the route from place A to place B
2. The distance between these two places
3. And the duration (in traffic)

Therefore I have the following code

```
var request = {
        origin:location1, 
        destination:location2,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,


    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
        {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            distance = "Die Entfernung zur Arbeit entspricht: "+ "<b>" +response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text +"</b>";
            distance += "<br/>Die vorausschauliche Fahrzeit betr&auml;gt: "+ "<b>"+response.routes[0].legs[0].duration_in_traffic.text +"</b>";
            document.getElementById("distance_road").innerHTML = distance;
        }

    });
```

In this code-exampel I can't get the duration_in_traffic. I think it is because I dont have a prmium plan?

So I was thinking about an other way. This URL give me a JSON object as a response. This JSON object includes the duration_in_traffic.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Bellheim&destination=Voeklingen&departure_time=now&key=MYKEY
```

But I don't know how to get the json object in javascript and I don't know how to extract the information from the json object.

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: The [quota plans](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits) say that you **can** use the API for distance calculation.

Comment: I know but not to get the duration_in_traffic?

Comment: You mentioned that you are able to get the `distance_in_traffic` in a `JSON`. Could you provide the `JSON`?

Comment: @SreetamDas As you can see in my latest replay (see the picture)

Comment: which picture ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation provided here, I'm assuming that you are receiving the following `JSON`:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361715
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13725
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

If the above **is** the response, then you can get the distance by using `<var_name>.rows.elements.distance`

---

> After looking at your image

---

you can access your `distance_in_traffic` using: `<var_name>.routes.0.legs.0.distance.<text/value>`

Comment: @OP, this should help, *assuming the nature of the `JSON`*

Comment: Thank you at first! :)
My Problem is:
1. I dont know how to get this JSON with JS
2. I dont know how I can use your answer

Comment: Can you paste your that you are currently using in [this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=iUS5Ta5RJ3)?